# Ryan Joiner Normality Test P-value

Tags: statistics, minitab

[image]

i tried a lot to calculate the Ryan Joiner(RJ) P-Value. is there any method or formula to calculate RJ P-Value.
i found how to calculate RJ value but unable to find the manual calcuation part for RJ P-Value. Minitab is calculating by some startegy . i want to know that how calculate it in manually.

please support me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The test statistic `RJ` needs to be compared to a critical value `CV` in order to make a determination of whether to reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.

The value of `CV` depends on the sample size and confidence level desired, and the values are empirically derived: generate large numbers of normally distributed datasets for each sample size `n`, calculate `RJ` statistic for each, then `CV` for `a=0.10` is the 10th percentile value of `RJ`.

Sidenote: For some reason I'm seeing a 90% confidence level used many places for Ryan-Joiner, when a 95% confidence is commonly used for other normality tests. I'm not sure why.

I recommend reading the original Ryan-Joiner 1976 paper:
https://www.additive-net.de/de/component/jdownloads/send/70-support/236-normal-probability-plots-and-tests-for-normality-thomas-a-ryan-jr-bryan-l-joiner

In that paper, the following critical value equations were empirically derived (I wrote out in python for convenience):

```py
def rj_critical_value(n, a=0.10)
    if a == 0.1:
        return 1.0071 - (0.1371 / sqrt(n)) - (0.3682 / n) + (0.7780 / n**2)
    elif a == 0.05:
        return 1.0063 - (0.1288 / sqrt(n)) - (0.6118 / n) + (1.3505 / n**2)
    elif a == 0.01: 
        return 0.9963 - (0.0211 / sqrt(n)) - (1.4106 / n) + (3.1791 / n**2)
    else:
        raise Exception("a must be one of [0.10, 0.05, 0.01]")
```

The `RJ` test statistic then needs to be compared to that critical value:

- If `RJ < CV`, then the determination is NOT NORMAL.
- If `RJ > CV`, then the determination is NORMAL.

Minitab is going one step further - working backwards to determine the value of `a` at which `CV == RJ`. This value would be the p-value you're referencing in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Minitab simply uses linear interpolation with the critical values to estimate the p-value. I tested with 17 different datasets and all the results are similar, although not exactly the same. I believe the small difference is due to rounding of the values reported by Minitab. However, when I calculate the test statistics and compare only the p-value, the results are always identical (rounded to the third decimal place).

For example, for `N=40`, the critical values are:

- For `alpha = 0.10`, `R_critical =0.97670384`
- For `alpha = 0.05`, `R_critical =0.97148399`
- For `alpha = 0.01`, `R_critical =0.95968573`

Now just interpolate the test statistics to find alpha. As `Ra=0.968`, the corresponding alpha is between `Rcritical=0.95968573` (`0.01`) and `Rcritical=0.97148399` (`0.05`). I calculated the critical values with the equation mentioned by [@brittohalloran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531441/17872198).

Just replace the values into the linear interpolation equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). See the image below for a step by step formula

[step by step calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rt45.png)

The result is a value close to what you obtained (`p_value = 0.040`).

> For p-value less than `1%`, minitab returns `"p < 0.010"` and for p-value greater than `10%`, it returns `"p > 0.100"`.

The script below estimates the `p-value` (I wrote out in python for convenience)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def rj_p_value(statistic, n):
    alphas = np.array([0.10, 0.05, 0.01])
    criticals = np.array(
        [1.0071 - (0.1371 / np.sqrt(n)) - (0.3682 / n) + (0.7780 / np.square(n)), # alpha = 0.10
         1.0063 - (0.1288 / np.sqrt(n)) - (0.6118 / n) + (1.3505 / np.square(n)), # alpha = 0.05
         0.9963 - (0.0211 / np.sqrt(n)) - (1.4106 / n) + (3.1791 / np.square(n)), # alpha = 0.01
        ])
    f = interpolate.interp1d(criticals, alphas)
    if statistic > max(criticals):
        return "p > 0.100"
    elif statistic < min(criticals):
        return "p < 0.010"
    else:
        return f(statistic) 
    
print(rj_p_value(statistic=0.968, n=40))
>>> 0.03818810764442493
```